# What rails IDE is used in this video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcMYbiZllLw

Comment: Fixed. Wasn't aware of this feature. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/)

It works on Mac and it's a generic text editor though, doesn't just work with rails! That would be equivalent to [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) if you were on Linux or [e-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) if you were on Windows.

Comment: its not really equivilent to vim at all. _maybe_ closer to emacs (not sure, not an emacs guy). vim is a completely different beast though.

Comment: @Matt: Agreed. But I think Vim is the closest to Textmate in GNU/Linux environments! Or is there any other editor you know that would be closer?

Comment: @Matt: Oh you suggested Emacs! Fair enough :)

Comment: For something to be like vim, I would think it was a modal editor. That was the only point I was trying to make

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not Textmate, It's BBedit or its free counterpart TextWrangler.